# show div content as default upon page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I followed this http://jsfiddle.net/6rSvf/ to make the links change div content when clicked. However can someone assist on how I can show a div as default and then when a link is clicked the content is replaced accordingly. Currently nothing is shown until a link is clicked.

Here is my JS.

```
$("#divtoggle").delegate("a", "click", function(e) {
    var toggled = ($(this).prop("id"));
    $("div#wrap").prop("class", toggled);
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#div1').show();
});
```

OR

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#togglediv1').click();
});
```

**UPDATE**

If the URL has the `#hash`, it will open that one, otherwise if will open the first one.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (window.location.hash && $(window.location.hash).length > 0) {
       $(window.location.hash).show();        
    } else {
        $('#div1').show();
    }
});
```

​
​

Answer (score 0):

You could trigger a click on the first anchor within your `#divtoggle` element:

```
$("#divtoggle").delegate("a", "click", function(e) {
    var toggled = ($(this).prop("id"));
    $("div#wrap").prop("class", toggled);
}).find('a').first().trigger('click');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always trigger `click` event explicitly to show default element ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6rSvf/46/)) -

```
$('#divtoggle a').first().click();
```

or select any element [with](http://jsfiddle.net/6rSvf/47/) -

```
$('#divtoggle a:eq(n)').click(); //`n` as index(starts from `0) of elements
```

Answer (score 0):

To is how you can do with the method you used to show / hide

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6rSvf/45/)**

```
$("div#wrap").prop("class", 'togglediv1');
$("#divtoggle").delegate("a", "click", function(e) {
    var toggled = ($(this).prop("id"));
    $("div#wrap").prop("class", toggled);
});​
```